# What is this, a capacitor, if so what value. It's a mystery to me

Tags: identification

[image: mysterious component unmarked]
If anyone know what kind of electrical component  this is can you help me identify it please. Here is a picture, and I do t remember what I pulled it from.

Comment: Hmm, that might be two ferrite beads. Can you provide a picture of where its legs enter the black cylinders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fairly certain its just a jumper, the two ferrite beads adds impedance to it.

Comment: Thanks the impedence thing was a bonus this was out of a guitar pedal

Answer (score 7):

It is just a wire with two ferrite beads and some adhesive to keep them on place.

Comment: A fancy jumper?

Comment: If you consider a component with ability to suppress high frequency energy in a controlled fashion as fancy, then yes.

Comment: thank you everyone!